# Does Drupal core include any comment spam prevention mechanism?

Tags: 9, comments

I have a Drupal 9 core website and I have allowed comments in it (approval needed).

The problem is that my website is flooded with spam boots posting links in pre-approved comments. This causes burden of filtering human-legitimate comments. I also desire not to install any modules and work only from the core.

Does Drupal core include any comment spam prevention mechanism?

I don't recall ever finding a core module which does it in the module's list. I went through [this Google search query](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASUM_enIL1022IL1022&sxsrf=APwXEde3WF7HsmTeeTbS1XWj40PZRYZZFQ:1681228270444&q=does%20drupal%20include%20any%20comment%20spam%20prevention%20mechanism%3F&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj79-Gul6L-AhUwRvEDHcQvDscQ7xYoAHoECBAQAQ&biw=1745&bih=845&dpr=1.1#ip=1) (`does drupal include any comment spam prevention mechanism?`) but I didn't find anything specific to comments and especially anything core-based.

Comment: No, there are contributed modules for anti spam, captcha, recaptcha and the like.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Googling is no research.

Comment: @leymannx From my knowledge of other Stack Exchange sites, Googling is indeed a legitimate research option for prior research before asking a question here. This is the way it is in Medical Sciences SE. Some websites don't obligate prior research besides running a Google query or checking the `man` (and quoting what was found wrong). I think you are exaggerating. If outside SE, more might be needed. I am not a programmer and didn't learn Drupal's source code, I can't research about a core way to do it besides familiarizing myself with Drupal and also pretty much what I had done above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Use contributed modules.